# Missing HTTP cache support for almost all forge endpoints

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to minimize traffic between my backend and https://developer.api.autodesk.com. I expected the forge APIs to consistently support standard HTTP caching with `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` headers, unfortunately this is not the case.

The only endpoint supporting `If-Modified-Since` I could find is [projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-GET/)

This is especially annoying for [:urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) which returns almost 100MB of data for one of my largest models (ignoring gzip).

Is HTTP cache support on your roadmap, preferably with `ETag` and `If-None-Match`?

**Edit:** Turns out this doesn't matter for requests with URNs. The document URN contains the document version, so I assume responses can be safely cached forever.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have If-Modified-Since header feature for model derivative, because if you upload a modified model, you have to explicitly make a call to translate it again.
In case you upload a new file with the same name, make sure to use header x-ads-force: true

Comment: Thanks for your response. The behavior you describe is understood. What I want from Forge is that you save the timestamp when the model changes and then return it for all request to the derivative API for this model as `Last-Modified` header. Alternatively hash the content and return a `Etag` header.